# Qt e Android - Pegar caminho de uma imagem da galeria

Tags: android, qt, galeria

Estou desenvolvendo um código para pegar uma imagem da `Galeria do Android`. Estou usando `QtAndroid` para escrever em Qt um código equivalente ao java.

Eu já abri a galeria, selecionei a imagem and e recebi o caminho, mas o retorno é o `MediaColumn` do arquivo e eu preciso do caminho absoluto.

Como eu posso pegar o caminho absoluto do arquivo usando `QAndroid` para escrever no Qt um código equivalente ao Java?

Aqui está o código:

imagepickerandroid.h

```
#ifndef IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H
#define IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H


#include <QObject>
#include <QtAndroidExtras>

#include <QDebug>

class imagePickerAndroid : public QObject, public QAndroidActivityResultReceiver
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    imagePickerAndroid();

    void buscaImagem();

    virtual void handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject & data);

signals:
    void imagemCaminhoSignal(QString);
};

#endif // IMAGEPICKERANDROID_H
```

imagepickerandroid.cpp

```
#include "imagepickerandroid.h"

imagePickerAndroid::imagePickerAndroid()
{

}

void imagePickerAndroid::buscaImagem()
{
    QAndroidJniObject ACTION_PICK = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent");
    if (ACTION_PICK.isValid() && intent.isValid())
    {
        intent.callObjectMethod("setAction", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", ACTION_PICK.object<jstring>());
        intent.callObjectMethod("setType", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QAndroidJniObject::fromString("image/*").object<jstring>());
        QtAndroid::startActivity(intent.object<jobject>(), 101, this);
        qDebug() << "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERRO";
    }
}

void imagePickerAndroid::handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data)
{
    qDebug() << "Trabalha com os dados";

    jint RESULT_OK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/app/Activity", "RESULT_OK");
    if (receiverRequestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        QString imagemCaminho = data.callObjectMethod("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;").callObjectMethod("getPath", "()Ljava/lang/String;").toString();
        emit imagemCaminhoSignal(imagemCaminho);

        qDebug() << imagemCaminho;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Caminho errado";
    }
}
```

Comment: Em geral você recebe uma URL com `content://` do android, não um caminho absoluto. A unica forma de realmente ler isso é usando a API em java, que envolveria criar um `java.io.File` para ler a URL. Não muito prático, mas acredito ser a unica forma que sempre funcionaria.

Comment: Pois é. O problema é que não consigo exibir a imagem no `QML` usando somente esta referência. Como eu posso fazer isto?

Comment: Uma opção é usar a api do java para ler a url e escrever em um arquivo no seu diretório de cache, e então ler de lá. Ou ainda: ler o arquivo para um `byte[]` na memória e passar isso para o construtor de `QPixmap`  para carregar a imagem e repassar ao QML. Não tenho nenhuma solução realmente boa.

Comment: E soluções como esta desta link https://github.com/eswarm/AutoSortD/blob/master/androidfiledialog.cpp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondendo minha própria pergunta

Aqui está o código para pegar o caminho completo de uma imagem da galeria do Android usando código em Qt equivalente ao Java:

```
#include "imagepickerandroid.h"

imagePickerAndroid::imagePickerAndroid()
{

}

void imagePickerAndroid::buscaImagem()
{
    QAndroidJniObject ACTION_PICK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/content/Intent", "ACTION_PICK", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    QAndroidJniObject EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore$Images$Media", "EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI", "Landroid/net/Uri;");

    QAndroidJniObject intent=QAndroidJniObject("android/content/Intent", "(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/net/Uri;)V", ACTION_PICK.object<jstring>(), EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.object<jobject>());

    if (ACTION_PICK.isValid() && intent.isValid())
    {
        intent.callObjectMethod("setType", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QAndroidJniObject::fromString("image/*").object<jstring>());
        QtAndroid::startActivity(intent.object<jobject>(), 101, this);
        qDebug() << "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERRO";
    }
}

void imagePickerAndroid::handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject &data)
{
    jint RESULT_OK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/app/Activity", "RESULT_OK");
    if (receiverRequestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        QAndroidJniObject uri = data.callObjectMethod("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;");
        QAndroidJniObject dadosAndroid = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore$MediaColumns", "DATA", "Ljava/lang/String;");
        QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
        jobjectArray projecao = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(1, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);
        jobject projacaoDadosAndroid = env->NewStringUTF(dadosAndroid.toString().toStdString().c_str());
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(projecao, 0, projacaoDadosAndroid);
        QAndroidJniObject contentResolver = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("getContentResolver", "()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;");
        QAndroidJniObject cursor = contentResolver.callObjectMethod("query", "(Landroid/net/Uri;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/database/Cursor;", uri.object<jobject>(), projecao, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        jint columnIndex = cursor.callMethod<jint>("getColumnIndex", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I", dadosAndroid.object<jstring>());
        cursor.callMethod<jboolean>("moveToFirst", "()Z");
        QAndroidJniObject resultado = cursor.callObjectMethod("getString", "(I)Ljava/lang/String;", columnIndex);
        QString imagemCaminho = "file://" + resultado.toString();
        emit imagemCaminhoSignal(imagemCaminho);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Caminho errado";
    }
}
```